# Can I bypass use of the WPF font cache?

Tags: wpf, fonts

We are developing a WPF/C# application and having trouble corrupt font caches.  Many of our users have old video drivers which are particularly buggy in regards to the font cache.  We've worked with individual users to upgrade the drivers which usually solves the problem, but the problem only comes to our attention after the user has experienced a problem which makes our software unusable (which makes it look like our bug, not microsoft's).

We use only 2 fonts in our application at the moment.  ***Can I tell WPF to bypass the font cache*** altogether to prevent these problems for our users when they're running our software?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider to not let the users with correct drivers suffer for those without.

Perhaps you can add a warning in the setup.

That said, you could [stop the cache service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999756/what-is-the-use-of-wpffontcache-service-in-wpf-wpffontcache-v0400-exe-taking-10) (it is a service) but you need to be an administrator to stop services.

You might also have a look at [clearing the font cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006436/systemfontfamilies-error-when-binding-to-combobox/7709424#7709424)

Or you could see if [delayed loading the fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745696/rendering-and-loading-fonts-into-the-fontcache-on-a-background-thread) will help.

Comment: Unfortunately, our software is usually installed by the client's IT department who runs the installer in large batches and tends to ignore warnings.  Delay loading the fonts hasn't been effective to prevent the cache from becoming corrupt.  We clear the cache and/or stop the service once we've been notified of a problem, but I'd like to avoid stopping the service altogether, which may have negative impacts on other software on their machine.  I'm looking for a way to bypass it just for my software where I can control it's impact.